# fopen mode w+ and reading the file?

Tags: php, fopen, mode

I'm going through all the modes and trying to understand where can you apply some of them, and I stumbled upon `w`. Now I understand how that mode works, but what's the purpose of `w+`? Obviously if we use `fopen` right after opening the file, it won't work since the file will be truncated, so I assume it's good to write something in the file and then read from it later on, so I decided to test it like so:

```
$handle = fopen('new.txt', 'w+');  
fwrite($handle, '123');  
$file = fread($handle, filesize('new.txt'));  
var_dump($file);  // string '' (length=0)
fclose($handle);
```

For some reason it doesn't read the contains of the file later.
Could someone explain to me please where could it applicable, and what is wrong with my code? `filesize` returns 3, so it doesn't delete the contents of the file, I assume that the `$handle` might be used from the moment we opened the file and it doesn't update? Then it confuses me even more why would we use mode `w+` and doing reading from a file at the same time?
**Edit:** I can understand even how I can write something in the file with `r+` and then check what I've written with using `fopen` again, like so:

```
$handle = fopen('new.txt', 'r+');  
fwrite($handle, '123');   
$handle = fopen('new.txt', 'r+');  
$file = fread($handle, filesize('new.txt'));  
var_dump($file);  
fclose($handle);
```

If I would do the same with `w+`, it would just delete the contents obviously, and I would not be able to read anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fopen()` with `w+` option opens the file for read/write at the beginning and truncates the length to 0. It's essentially the same as writing to a new empty file.

See fopen() usage here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

w+ is mainly used to "read back" what you've written. In your case you are using fread() function which reads "forward" from your pointer which is currently sitting at the end of the file after doing fwrite(), which would explain why you are getting empty contents.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

@Ye. is right about the pointer.  Once you have executed fwrite, then the pointer will be at the end of the file.  What you need is **[fseek()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php)** to go back to the beginning of the file.

```
$handle = fopen('new.txt', 'w+');
fwrite($handle, '123');
fseek($handle, 0);
$file = fread($handle, filesize('new.txt'));
var_dump($file);  // string '123' (length=3)
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I forgot about the pointer, now it all makes sense